# Chrome headless not working as root with --no-sandbox?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run google-chrome headless and I am getting this error:

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu http://www.google.com --no-sandbox

[0405/021207.884406:WARNING:headless_browser_main_parts.cc(83)] Cannot create Pref Service with no user data dir.
[0405/021207.901462:ERROR:vaapi_wrapper.cc(573)] Could not get a valid VA display
```

Comment: Where you try to execute chromium?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another user you can login and use, one that isn't root? This should fix the issue.